# Drawing LineString to right (horizontal) direction only

Tags: openlayers, linestring

We use Vue.js 2 and OpenLayers 4.6.5. The picture looks as folowing:

[image]

The user draws the first line, for example, from the bottom upward and makes a click to finish the first line. Then he draws next and last line and makes the last click to finish it. He can draw the second (last) line in any direction, but I need to allow him to draw in right, horizontal direction only.

How to allow drawing LineString to right (horizontal) direction only? The code looks as following.

Style function:

```js
getCallOutStyle (feature, title, zIndex) {
  if (title) {
    const styles = []
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry()

    geometry.forEachSegment(function (start, end) {
      styles.push(new Style({
        geometry: new LineString([start, end]),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 }),
        text: new Text({
          text: title.toString(),
          font: '17px "Roboto", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
          textAlign: 'left',
          overflow: true,
          placement: 'line',
          textBaseline: 'bottom',
          stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 })
        }),
        zIndex
      }))
    })

    if (styles.length >= 2) {
      styles[0].text_.setText('')
      styles.splice(styles.length)
    }

    return styles
  }
},
```

Drawing:

```js
callOut (callOut) {
  if (!callOut) {
    this.callOutDraw.un('drawend', this.onCallOutDrawEnd)
    this.map.removeInteraction(this.callOutDraw)
    return
  }

  const draw = new Draw({
    source: this.vectorLayer.getSource(),
    type: 'LineString',
    maxPoints: 3
  })
  this.callOutDraw = draw
  this.map.addInteraction(this.callOutDraw)

  draw.on('drawend', this.onCallOutDrawEnd)
},
onCallOutDrawEnd (event) {
  this.callOutFeature = event.feature
},
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Please edit your question and in the body of the question explain more in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've added UPDATE section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a geometry function in the draw to ensure the third point is always to the right of the second point

```
  const draw = new Draw({
    source: this.vectorLayer.getSource(),
    type: 'LineString',
    maxPoints: 3,
    geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
      if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
      }
      if (coordinates.length > 2) {
        coordinates[2][0] = Math.max(coordinates[1][0], coordinates[2][0]);
        coordinates[2][1] = coordinates[1][1];
      }
      geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);
      return geometry;
    }
  })
```

Comment: It works! You are superstar! Thanks a lot!